# Перевод блока Связанные вопросы

Tags: дефект, локализация

На странице вопросов появился новый блок "Related questions" (Связанные вопросы)

В данном блоке имеются две нелокализованные фразы:

- Related questions
- Load 5 more related questions

см. пример на странице 
 [Полный путь к конфигу Apache (OpenServer) в Windows](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1506877/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9-%D0%BF%D1%83%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BA-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%84%D0%B8%D0%B3%D1%83-apache-openserver-%D0%B2-windows)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

## UPD1

забавно:сейчас перешел на тот же вопрос и теперь похожие вопросы справа на странице опять справа

- Либо откат,
- либо кеш,
- либо A-B тестирование.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Интересно, зачем они вообще этот блок туда запихали... Справа теперь пустота

Comment: @SwaD я полагаю продолжают движение в сторону мобилок. Отдельную версию для мобилок упразднили и теперь есть одна универсальная. И десктопная версия постепенно меняется в угоду мобильной верстке.

Comment: Походу, это для задающих вопросы... Как только дан ответ, связанные вопросы вырисовываются по старому справа... Больше похоже на акцентирование внимания, хотя я думал, что это для всех вопросов. Вопрос задал, не разобравшись

Comment: @SwaD, забавно...сейчас перешел на тот же вопрос...и сейчас там страница выглядит так: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xi2Mm.png (похожие вопросы справа)... Либо откат, либо кеш, либо A-B тестирование.

Comment: Я не заходил в вопрос, перешел после комментария и у меня похожие сообщения отобразились справа.. Может есть какой алгоритм? )

Comment: @SwaD как говорил классик: "У меня была какая-то тактика и я ее придерживался". Возможно, но времени выяснять его у меня, к сожалению, нет...несмотря на любопытство

Comment: @SwaD таки A/B тестирование

Comment: @SwaD и таки откат тоже...сейчас ответ напишу -_-

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Данный блок исчез также быстро как и появился.**
После ряда комментариев я перешел на указанный мной вопрос с данным блоком... и я его там не нашел.
Любопытство взяло верх и я пошел на meta.stackexchange за ответами

Оказалось, что данную функциональность разворачивали в ходе эксперимента:
https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/423143/a-b-testing-related-questions-within-the-answers-list-experiment-has-graduated

Предполагалось устроить A/B тестирование на основном сайте и при успехе, после чего развернуть на основном сайте...
Но нечаянно развернули на всех сайтах сети, поэтому пришлось спешно откатывать.

На данном этапе данная функциональность доступна только на основном сайте.

Подробности можно найти по ссылке:
[Why are "related questions" suddenly appearing above the answer input (instead of in the right sidebar) for unanswered questions?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/387755/why-are-related-questions-suddenly-appearing-above-the-answer-input-instead-o)

**Вопрос на данный момент неактуален.**

Comment: Думаю актуален на будущее, заранее перевести текст )

Comment: @SwaD можно, конечно... но это решать тем у кого есть право заапрувить перевод.